# Why is there no delay between same-line printing?

Tags: python, printing, output, delay

```
print 'foo',
time.sleep(1)
print 'bar'
```

This seems to run `time.sleep(1)` first, then prints `"foo bar"` all at once.

However, printing both `foo` and `bar` on its own lines produces the expected delay between the print statements:

```
print 'foo'
time.sleep(1)
print 'bar'
```

Is there something that stacks all print statements until a new line character is received?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print` by default prints to sys.stdout and it is line-buffered. you could flush the buffer each time after a print statement

```
import time
import sys

print 'foo'
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
print 'bar
```

reference: [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

read also: [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)